# Android TileView from moagrius want to see menu

Tags: java, android

I use the tileView lib from moagrius https://github.com/moagrius/TileView.

It works very well on full display. But I also want to see the menu which was created in the layouts. Does anybody know how does it work?

`
    public class testextends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


     TileView tileView = new TileView( this );
    tileView.setSize( 200, 300 );  // the original size of the untiled image
    tileView.setBackgroundColor( 0xFFe7e7e7 );
    tileView.addDetailLevel(1f, "tiles/125_1_1.png");
    setContentView( tileView );
}}`
```

I think the problem is that I'm using setcontentView twice. How can I change the TileView as normal view ?

Answer (score 0):

go to the layout.xml create a second view and than

remove:
 setContentView( tileView );

and add instead of this:
   ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test)).addView(tileView);